# esbuild ошибка: "Two output files share the same path but have different contents"

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, vite

Я начинающий программист на React js. Собрал проект на vite и все было нормально, но в какой то момент при запуске `npx vite` сборщик **esbuild** начал выдавать ошибку:

:

```
✘ [ERROR] Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js.map

✘ [ERROR] Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js
```

При этом самих файлов я не нашел. Как я понимаю, в каких то модулях несколько output'ов пытаются перезаписть один файл.  Если поудалять все пакеты из npm (nano-id, gh-pages) то все запускается. В проекте ипользуются таблицы стилей, компоненты, импроты реакта и других модулей. [Ссылка на репозиторий.](https://github.com/Digidr0/tenzies)

лог ошибок:

```
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js.map
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js
    at failureErrorWithLog (S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1624:15)
    at S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1266:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1046:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1264:7)
    at S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1377:14
    at S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:678:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:775:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (S:\Code\React\scrimba.com\tenzies\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:644:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: null,
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\\.vite\\deps_temp\\React.js.map'
    },
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: null,
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\\.vite\\deps_temp\\React.js'
    }
  ],
```

В чем заключается проблема, и как собрать проект используя нужные мне модули?

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО

В подчиненном компоненте **`<Question />`** был вызван `import { useState } from "React";` так же, как и в родительском компоненте **`<App />`**. Удаление этой строчки решило проблему.